# printf output running over into next line

Tags: bash-script, printf

I have created Bash SS in `vi`.  My output is running over into the line below it.  I am new to UNIX so I'm trying to learn.  My output is displayed using `printf`.

```
printf "%-15s %15s %15s %2d\n %2s " $name $days $phone $start $time
```

The output looks like this for example

```
name       days       phone      start 

time name    days       phone      start

time name    days       phone      start 

etc...
```

How do I get all five of my variables to print on same line?

Comment: You put the `\n` line *after* the last arg.

Comment: This is not a typo - the asker deliberately used malformed syntax because he/she was unaware of how to properly form the command. This should be reopened and should never have been closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your command:

```
printf "%-15s %15s %15s %2d\n %2s " $name $days $phone $start $time
```

Your problem:

```
'...\n %2s'
```

You're inserting a newline before `$time`. Stop that. Do:

```
printf '%-15s %15s %15s %2d %2s\n' \
    "$name" "$days" "$phone" "$start" "$time"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked like a charm.  For some reason I thought that \n was for all numbers.  I should have used the printf manual.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @mikeserv's answer, you can see the complete list of format controls for output from `man 1 printf`:

```
   \"     double quote    
   \\     backslash    
   \a     alert (BEL)    
   \b     backspace    
   \c     produce no further output    
   \e     escape    
   \f     form feed    
   \n     new line    
   \r     carriage return    
   \t     horizontal tab    
   \v     vertical tab    
   \NNN   byte with octal value NNN (1 to 3 digits)    
   \xHH   byte with hexadecimal value HH (1 to 2 digits)    
   \uHHHH Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character with hex value HHHH (4 digits)    

   \UHHHHHHHH
          Unicode character with hex value HHHHHHHH (8 digits)    

   %%     a single %    
   %b     ARGUMENT as a string with `\' escapes interpreted, except that 
          octal escapes are of the form \0 or \0NNN
```

You should read `man <command name>` to learn how to use command in any `*nix` OS.

Comment: `man` answers are my favorite answers. Note that for `printf` in particular, though, the majority of information is included in the C-specific `printf(3) man` page as opposed to the shell-specific `printf(1) man` page.

Comment: @mikeserv: What do you mean "opposed"? I think `printf(1)` is only a short documentation of `printf(3)`, not "opposed".

Comment: I meant *majority* as opposed to *minority.* Sorry if i was unclear. I upvoted you anyway. Definitely one should start with `printf(1)` - but because its just a carry-over of C's `print function` it's expected youll go looking in its docs for more info.